# How much of a security threat to the PC is a SIM card running applets when plugged into a USB modem?

Tags: simcard

**Background**
A customer complained to a mobile phone company that they were receiving messages that were leaving the screen turned on until it was noticed by the customer (usually many hours) by which time the battery was almost completely drained, and that the messages did not appear in the inbox (or anywhere else).

- The mobile phone company said that it runs applets on the SIM card, and that's why the messages do not appear in the inbox.

**The problem is**
The customer also plugs this SIM card into a USB modem, which they plug into a computer.

**The question is**
When the customer plugs this SIM card into a USB modem, which they plug into a computer (running Windows 10), just how much hacking, password-stealing, etc. can that mobile phone company, theoretically do?

Obviously I would think that the answer would be limitless.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39191395/829970 and https://simhacks.github.io/ for some information about what you can do with SIM applets.